# Redirect URI mismatch - Get Google access tokens (OAuth 2)

Tags: java, google-oauth, redirect, google-api-java-client, developer-console

I am trying to use the Gmail API from Java and followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow which uses Javascript API to get user permission and once done, returns with code. Also front end of my application is at http://localhost:1234. I am sending this code via ajax(CORS) to backend of application at http://localhost:8081/gmail/test endpoint and I am using Google API Client Library for Java to get access and refresh tokens using the code :

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                     new NetHttpTransport(),
                      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                      clientId,
                      clientKey,
                      code,
                      REDIRECT_URI)
                      .execute();
```

But I end up getting 400 bad request due to REDIRECT_URI mismatch. In google API developer console I have mentioned both http://localhost:8081 and http://localhost:1234 as authorized redirect URI and I tried using both in above code but still doesn't help me with the error. I need some help to fix this issue and tell me the exact REDIRECT_URI to be used.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**:
Set the redirect URI in API console as http://localhost and http://localhost:1234  in the code.

Comment: it would be good to point out what value the REDIRECT_URI parameter is set to

Comment: Hi I tried to set it to http://localhost:8081 and http://localhost:1234, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the redirect URI is configured in the API console, and then used in your app. The two must be character-for-character *identical*. I suggest post a screenshot from the API console and the code fragment where it is defined in your app.

Comment: I set the redirect URI in API console as http://localhost (without port number)and http://localhost:1234 in the code. It worked.